# Fourier series: term-by-term Laplace transform.

Tags: fourier-series, laplace-transform

Quick question:
If a Fourier series is uniformly convergent should the term-by-term Laplace transform of the series equal the result of the periodic function theorem for the Laplace transform?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, because the Fourier series defines a periodic function for $-\infty<t<\infty$, whereas the periodic function theorem of the Laplace transform refers to functions which are zero for $t<0$. The Laplace transform of a periodic function (defined for $-\infty<t<\infty$) does not exist.